# How to achieve a not null return in this function by using Kotlin?

Tags: function, kotlin, while-loop, try-catch, do-while

```
       lateinit var x:String

          private fun defineTheIDofTheRoom ():String   {
             
          while (x != "") {
              x = intent.getStringExtra("ID1")!!
              x = intent.getStringExtra("ID2")!!
              x = intent.getStringExtra("ID3")!!
              x = intent.getStringExtra("ID4")!!

              
            }
        return x
     }
```

//ı want this function give me a result which is not null (String) and ı will use it somewhere else.3 of them will give null as a result, only one of them will be not null... if somebody can help ı will be glad thanks a lot from now on...

Comment: You have to elaborate on your question and tag it with the appropriate language and frameworks. _Generally speaking you need to return a value on the function like `return x;` for example._

Comment: There are several issues with the code here, but perhaps the first question you have to ask yourself is: what should your function return if x _is_ the empty string?

Comment: @gidds ım sure that one of them will not return empty string...

Comment: @MaiconMauricio ı changed it, sorry to forget return x...

Comment: @jayzxll If I had a pound for every ‘impossible’ condition that my code had generated…  But it's not me you have to convince; it's the compiler.

Comment: @gidds the thing is here, code doesnt even go after the first try through others..so ı guess the problem is why in my while block it executes the first line but not the others, maybe ı have a mistake in while block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 3 of them will give null as a result, only one of them will be not null...

> the thing is here, code doesnt even go after the first try through others..so ı guess the problem is why in my while block it executes the first line but not the others, maybe ı have a mistake in while block?

If the first 3 are not actually null, they will assign a value to `x` but that value will immediately be overwritten; the *only* effect of the

```
x = intent.getStringExtra("ID1")!!
x = intent.getStringExtra("ID2")!!
x = intent.getStringExtra("ID3")!!
```

lines is to throw an exception if any of them is `null`. I suspect you want

```
x = (intent.getStringExtra("ID1") ?: intent.getStringExtra("ID2") ?: intent.getStringExtra("ID3") ?: intent.getStringExtra("ID4"))!!
```

and no `while` loop. I'd only use that last `!!` if you specifically want to crash if all 4 are `null` and `?: "some default case"` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put `return x` outside of the `while` block like this

```
private fun defineTheIDofTheRoom (): String {
        while (x != "") {
            x = intent.getStringExtra("ID1")!!
            x = intent.getStringExtra("ID2")!!
            x = intent.getStringExtra("ID3")!!
            x = intent.getStringExtra("ID4")!!
        }
        return x
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but ı just mistaken there, already ı use return x outside of the while block...